# How to Extract clob XML attribute name list from oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, clob

[image]I need to make a report by extracting xml element name from clob data in oracle 11g. Product table stores its attribute as clob XML, which can have multiple attributes stored on it. Value stored in below format:

200.0Manufacturer1235/V

Here i need a report which should contain attributes name like Rebate,SellerOwnerID,SellerOwnerValue. I can extract the clob data but i don't know how to get list of attributes name.

Comment: Not showing XML in correct way so i have uploaded image.

Comment: Please give me the sample xml

Comment: <attrs><attr name="Rebate"><double>200.0</double></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerID"><string>Manufacturer</string></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerValue"><string>1235/V</string></attr></attrs>

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below query to get the desired output

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (COLUMN_VALUE, '/attr/@name') attribute,
       EXTRACTVALUE (COLUMN_VALUE, '/attr/double') double,
       EXTRACTVALUE (COLUMN_VALUE, '/attr/string') string
  FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<attrs><attr name="Rebate"><double>200.0</double></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerID"><string>Manufacturer</string></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerValue"><string>1235/V</string></attr></attrs>'),'/attrs/attr')))
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh , There is an issue with writing query in such way. I will explain the complexity. Table name Product Column name attribute. Column attribute can store XML which has multiple attributes and this is not fixed. For the sample i have attaches it has like 3 attributes but other product can have 40-50 attributes. Can we write something generic?

Comment: Can you please share that complex xml

Comment: XML i have attached is extracted from DB clob column. The actual XML has different set of structure. When we process the Product XML we save product attributes in attached XML format. Just for another instance i am attaching another sample from different product.

Comment: <attrs> <attr name="Rebate"> <double>100.0</double> </attr> <attr name="Expiry"> <string>(through 7/20/14)</string> </attr> <attr name="PaperSize"> <string>Legal</string> </attr> <attr name="SellerOwnerID1"> <string>Manufacturer</string> </attr> <attr name="SellerOwnerValue1"> <string>Manufacturer</string> </attr> <attr name="SellerOwnerValue2"> <string>QQ1234</string></attr> <attr name="SellerOwnerID2"> <string>QQ1235</string></attr> <attr name="StartingAt"><double>449.0</double></attr> <attr name="Usage"> <string>Home Office,Workgroup</string> </attr> </attrs>

Comment: XMLSEQUENCE is deprecated and Oracle recommends that you use the XMLTABLE

Comment: I am extracting these XML by executing this query. select DBMS_LOB.substr(d.attributes, 3000) 
from product p
where attributes is not null

Answer (score 0):

```
with abc as ( select * from  
(select 'Prod1' prod_name,xmltype('<attrs><attr name="Rebate"><double>200.0</double></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerID"><string>Manufacturer</string></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerValue"><string>1235/V</string></attr></attrs>') xxx from dual
union all 
select 'Prod2',xmltype('<attrs><attr name="Rebate"><double>200.0</double></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerID"><string>Manufacturer</string></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerValue"><string>1235/V</string></attr><attr name="Rebate"><double>200.0</double></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerID"><string>Manufacturer</string></attr><attr name="SellerOwnerValue"><string>1235/V</string></attr></attrs>') from dual
))
select prod_name,attr_name,attr_type,attr_value from abc,xmltable('attrs/attr'
                passing  abc.xxx
                columns
                    attr_name varchar2(30) path '@name',
                    attr_type varchar2(30) path '*/name()',
                    attr_value varchar2(30) path '*/text()'
                      );
```